# High write endurance 256Gb micro sd card

Tags: microsd, sd-card, reliability, sdxc

I previously had a Samsung High Endurance 256Gb sd card. Despite it supported fstrim and filesystems where mounted with `discard` enabled, [it stopped working tonight](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386886). The write counter from Smartctl data says it has reached 3328Gb which exactly matches 13 times the capacity of the sd card.

This means unlike most flash memories which can be rewritten thousands of times, that those sd cards have only a lifespan of 13 write cycles. **And with those only 13 write cycles, they are rated high endurance.**

I’m putting the firmware of my rooted Android device on the sd card hence the intense write activity. That Samsung high Endurance sd card only lasted 8 months of Google Play updates.

**Can you find a 256Gb micro sd card being high endurance not in name but actually in practice** ?

Comment: No flash/sd card will live forever. Some will last minutes, some years. The manufacturers will guarantee for some period that if one fails they will replace it. No manufacturer will ever guarantee the specific life of any single card. They usually fail if there's a write error, but not always. Your linked answer sounds like this happened, write fail triggers firmware lock; you can read but no longer write.

Comment: @Tetsujin the problem is like I bought a new car which only ran 1300miles and was labelled `high durability.` It was high endurance in name only. **By high endurance, I m buying things expected to last far longer not less**.

Comment: And if you buy 100 or more you'll see that on average, they do last a lot longer. A sample-set of one is still a random chance. I used to get through literally thousands of these every year for work; I've seen this theory in action. Some ran for years, some died in weeks.

Comment: @Tetsujin : I bought a new one of the same model : it lasted 3 weeks in the same conditions.

Comment: Then send it back & complain.

Comment: @Tetsujin reimbursed. The problem as explained by the question is to find a more durable alternative.

Comment: Buy the cheapest one you can find & see how long it lasts. If it's no better than the expensive one, blame the write device. I used to get through literally thousands of these things every year for work. Some last, some don't - but if you get a repeating fail pattern, it's the device not the cards.

Comment: @Tetsujin not sure the 3 years old phone is a problem.

Comment: …but you're not sure it isn't. You have a sample set of two & a test device count of one. It's not like you can really work out the percentages from such a small data set.